# separate class that implements keylistener and jpanel

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm trying to create two threads, with one using keylistener and pipedoutputstream to give input to the other thread(pipedinputstream). The way I implemented it: two Runnable classes in Main, at which main(String[] args) uses an ExecutorService to control those two threads. With little understanding of how to use a few of these classes, I barely put up something as follow (skipped some code):

```
public class Main {

final static PipedOutputStream pipedOut = new PipedOutputStream();
final static PipedInputStream pipedIn = new PipedInputStream();

class ListenerOutput extends JPanel implements KeyListener, Runnable {
    int eventKey;
    char c;

    ListenerOutput() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        addKeyListener(this);

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(new ListenerOutput());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    {...}
}

class GameLoop implements Runnable {...}

main(String[] args){
    try {
        pipedOut.connect(pipedIn);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    service.execute(new Main().new ListenerOutput());
    service.execute(new Main().new GameLoop());
}
```

The problem is on the line `f.getContentPane().add(new ListenerOutput());`.It's recursive, to no end. I know it would throw the StackOverflow error. But still, I'm quite confused with what to do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: f.getContentPane().add(this);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the constructor, this line provides a hint:

```
addKeyListener(this);
```

To avoid the recursion:

```
// f.getContentPane().add(new ListenerOutput());
f.getContentPane().add(this);
```

So the JFrame `f` uses the object under construction similar as the KeyListener.